# Align divs Horizontally with image size fixed. (Horizontal Scroll bar may come)

Tags: html, css

I've two divs. It contains two chart with width 800px and height 400px each. I want them horizontally aligned.

Also, they **shouldn't** change there alignment or image size if monitor/browser size changes. Automatic horizontal scroll bar (or vertical if required) should come.

I've tried many options but couldn't get what I am looking for. :(

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{
        font-size: 28px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #left{
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        margin:0;
    }
    #right{
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-wrap:none;
    }
```

This is the latest version of CSS I tried.

Comment: Can you post some html and css please :D and some images you are trying to use

Comment: I think I've given enough information what it is require for a reply, like size of it and each image is under one div and both divs are under one "papa" (parent) div. Images are confidential so I cannot share, no use of sharing dummy images you can google it out yourself.:)

Comment: If don't want to post image then don't post. But Post atleast html and css which you are used. It make easier for other to answer.

Comment: Thanks for considering to reply. I've updated latest version of CSS I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this should satisfy what you're looking for. Here's a [working example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92oc9v3t/). I've added notes to the CSS to describe how I got it to work.

```
#container{
    /* Since you know the width of the images, we can set
    the container width. This will force the browser to
    draw a horizontal scrollbar when the width is too small */
    width: 1600px;
    /* This is a little trick to make the container as large
    as the elements inside it, even though they are set to
    float: left */
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left,
#right{
    /* display: inline-block does not work because is adds space
    around each element, making them wider than the container and
    forcing the second image down below the first, so we can use
    float: left instead */
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" /></div>
    <div id="right"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/444444" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent Solution. It worked perfectly.
+1 for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`display:flex` and `margin` will do the trick here. And remove `width:50%;` if do not want to change image size.

Check following: Here i change image size to display properly.

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#container > div {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
    
img{
      width:400px;
      height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="left"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></div>
<div id="right"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5e8o9pq/)**

Comment: Hi Ketan, Thanks for your reply. This solution also worked for me but I've already used the solution by Russell

Comment: @RajatAgarwal No. worry glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you could show us what you have tried. Anyways I hope this is what you are expecting. [demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwBzmm)

```
         <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                   <div id="1" class="box left">
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="800" width="400">
                   </div>
                  <div id="1" class="box right">
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="800" width="400">

          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Also, it would be great if you can explain the usage of all the divs you used?

Answer (score 0):

Display inline-block will work, here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/w913sbro/

You can also try adding this to your #container:

```
display:flex;
```

as by default flex will align in row style.(horizontal).